# How to deploy a WordPress in Rancher

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

I read [this](https://vsys.host/how-to/how-to-deploy-wp-on-kubernetes-via-rancher) link and [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/) one to see how to deploy a simple WordPress application but I cannot.

With the first link I get error that PVC is not bound, and with the second link I get this error in the `kubectl describe pod_name`:

```
pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims
```

I even tried manually to run `kubectl apply -k .` as per in k8s docs but it failed.

I run rancher on docker:

```
docker run -d -p80:80 -p443:443 --privileged rancher/rancher:latest
```

Do you please help me how to run a WordPress application to run?

I also tried other links and docs but none of them were a successful attempt.

Answer (score -1):

1. Describe PVC and check events.
2. It seems it's not able to create a volume. Cross check on what storage provisioner your using.
3. If you haven't got any storage provisioned like portworx or csi, try to create volumes using `EmptyDir`

   1. Create a YAML file for the `emptyDir` PV; let's call it `emptydir-pv.yaml`:

      ```yaml
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: PersistentVolume
      metadata:
        name: my-emptydir-pv
      spec:
        capacity:
          storage: 1Gi
        volumeMode: Filesystem
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
        storageClassName: ""
        hostPath:
          path: /data/my-emptydir
      ```

      This YAML file defines an `emptyDir` PV named `my-emptydir-pv` with a capacity of 1Gi and a `hostPath` that specifies the directory on the node where the data will be stored.
   2. Apply the PV definition to your cluster:

      ```
      kubectl apply -f emptydir-pv.yaml
      ```
   3. Create a Pod that uses the `emptyDir` PV. Here's an example Pod YAML; let's call it `my-pod.yaml`:

      ```
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: Pod
      metadata:
        name: my-pod
      spec:
        volumes:
          - name: my-emptydir-volume
            persistentVolumeClaim:
              claimName: my-emptydir-pv
        containers:
          - name: my-container
            image: nginx
            volumeMounts:
              - name: my-emptydir-volume
                mountPath: /data
      ```

   This Pod definition references the previously created `emptyDir` PV and mounts it to the `/data` directory in the Pod container.

   4. Apply the Pod definition to your cluster

      ```
      kubectl apply -f my-pod.yaml
      ```

Please note that this approach is suitable for scenarios where you need temporary storage or shared storage among containers within the same node. The data in the `emptyDir` volume is not persistent, and it will be lost if the Pod is deleted or rescheduled to a different node.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's a little hard for me to read the `yaml` code. Please edit your answer and beautify that with the `markdown` syntax.

Comment: ```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: my-emptydir-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: ""
  hostPath:
    path: /data/my-emptydir
```

Comment: ```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: my-emptydir-volume
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: my-emptydir-pv
  containers:
    - name: my-container
      image: nginx
      volumeMounts:
        - name: my-emptydir-volume
          mountPath: /data
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77425552/edit please click this and edit your answer. Don't write answers in the comments

Comment: You should almost never directly create PersistentVolumes, nor should you use `hostPath` type volumes.  The cluster can normally create a PV on its own given a PersistentVolumeClaim.  A `hostPath` volume just references a directory on whichever node the Pod is running on, and it's very possible to misplace data if a new Pod using the volume is scheduled on a different node.